# postfix TLS configuration for incoming gmx-mail

Tags: postfix, configuration, tls, starttls

I set up my mailserver with postfix 2.7.1 and dovecot 1.2.15 and everything seemed to work just fine, but now I found out that people using @gmx.net addresses cannot send emails to me and rather receive the error message

```
Connected to <MYIPADDRESS> but sender was rejected.
Remote host said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
```

/var/log/mail.log shows:

```
postfix/smtpd[22743]: connected to mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]
postfix/smtpd[22743]: disconnect from mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]
```

a more detailed log tells me:

```
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostname: mailout-de.gmx.net ~? 127.0.0.0/8
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostaddr: 213.165.64.23 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostname: mailout-de.gmx.net ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostaddr: 213.165.64.23 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostname: mailout-de.gmx.net ~? [::1]/128
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostaddr: 213.165.64.23 ~? [::1]/128
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_list_match: mailout-de.gmx.net: no match
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_list_match: 213.165.64.23: no match
postfix/smtpd[22743]: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/anvil
postfix/smtpd[22743]: send attr request = connect
postfix/smtpd[22743]: send attr ident = smtp:213.165.64.23
postfix/smtpd[22743]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute name: status
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute value: 0
postfix/smtpd[22743]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: count
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute name: count
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute value: 1
postfix/smtpd[22743]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute name: rate
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute value: 1
postfix/smtpd[22743]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute name: (end)
postfix/smtpd[22743]: > mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]: 220 <MYDOMAIN> ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
postfix/smtpd[22743]: watchdog_pat: 0x7f1549946d00
postfix/smtpd[22743]: < mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]: HELO mailout-de.gmx.net
postfix/smtpd[22743]: > mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]: 250 <MYDOMAIN>
postfix/smtpd[22743]: watchdog_pat: 0x7f1549946d00
postfix/smtpd[22743]: < mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]: MAIL FROM:<SomeAddress@gmx.net>
postfix/smtpd[22743]: > mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
postfix/smtpd[22743]: watchdog_pat: 0x7f1549946d00
postfix/smtpd[22743]: < mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]: QUIT
postfix/smtpd[22743]: > mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]: 221 2.0.0 Bye
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostname: mailout-de.gmx.net ~? 127.0.0.0/8
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostaddr: 213.165.64.23 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostname: mailout-de.gmx.net ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostaddr: 213.165.64.23 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostname: mailout-de.gmx.net ~? [::1]/128
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_hostaddr: 213.165.64.23 ~? [::1]/128
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_list_match: mailout-de.gmx.net: no match
postfix/smtpd[22743]: match_list_match: 213.165.64.23: no match
postfix/smtpd[22743]: send attr request = disconnect
postfix/smtpd[22743]: send attr ident = smtp:213.165.64.23
postfix/smtpd[22743]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute name: status
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute value: 0
postfix/smtpd[22743]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
postfix/smtpd[22743]: input attribute name: (end)
postfix/smtpd[22743]: disconnect from mailout-de.gmx.net[213.165.64.23]
```

So gmx just does not issue the STARTTLS command, right? But why?
I do not understand why other mailservers can connect to mine but gmx cannot and why gmx can connect to any other mailserver but not to mine.

My /etc/postfix/main.cf is like the following:
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
    biff = no
    append_dot_mydomain = no
    readme_directory = no

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/my_mail_cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/my_mail_cert.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/my_mail_ca_cert.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
debug_peer_list = mailout-de.gmx.net #log problematic host
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

myhostname = <MYHOSTNAME>
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.org, , localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = <MYDOMAIN>
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of your config file, you have `smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt`, this requires all inbound SMTP clients to use TLS. If the inbound client doesn't support TLS, then the connection will fail. (This seems likely to be the case for gmx.net, given the error message.)

If you set `smtpd_tls_security_level = may`, then you should be able to get email from servers that don't support TLS. (This appears to be set higher up in your file, but is then overridden by the encrypt setting later.)

Comment: That's the reason why `postconf -n` output is always preferred over pasting the contents of `main.cf`.

Comment: Thanks! That's it. I had `smtpd_tls_security_level` twice, the second one overriding the first.