# Postfix Failed to Receive Email

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am trying to set up a mailing server with postfix and dovecot in ubuntu 12.04 following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin). All seems to have worked out correctly and when I try this `echo test | mail email1@example.org` everything works out as expected. But when I try to send a mail to the server from my gmail account I get this error

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     email1@example.org

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain example.org by aspmx.l.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4001:c05::1a].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 m1si13660174ige.61 - gsmtp
```

After failing to mail I tried to test the mail server with [this](http://mxtoolbox.com/) and I got 1 error because my HTTPS certificate was invalid, and 7 warnings because of my custom SMTP banner and missing SPF records. Any ideas on how I change my HTTPS cert and if it has the problem with gmail?

I also tried to test sending mail online from [here](https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server) and I got this result:

```
Resolving hostname...
Connecting...
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
220 floatnet.org ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
250-floatnet.org
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: underworldseed@gmail.com
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

RCPT TO: email1@floatnet.org
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Message sending failed.
```

This is my `main.cf` file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#smtpd_use_tls=yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination

#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = floatnet.org
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination = floatnet.org, vps2473.directvps.nl, localhost.directvps.nl, localhost
mydestination = localhost 
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
#smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
#smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth-client
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
```

Comment: Please post the output of command `postconf -n` and `postconf -M`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there are two different error messages above although the problem was same: **Failed to receive email**.

The first error was came when you send email from GMAIL. It is failed with error

```
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain domain.org by aspmx.l.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4001:c05::1a].
```

The reason why Google reject your email was because the MX record of floatnet.org was pointed to Gmail server instead to postfix server.

```
$ dig floatnet.org MX +short
20 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
30 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
30 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
30 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
30 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

Solution: **fix your MX record**.

---

The second error was revealed when you test your SMTP server.

```
  Must issue a STARTTLS command first
```

This error was **possible** duplicate of this question [postfix TLS configuration for incoming gmx-mail](https://serverfault.com/questions/438104/postfix-tls-configuration-for-incoming-gmx-mail). The proposed solution  is change `smtpd_tls_security_level` to "may" instead "encrypt".

Comment: I don't see `smtpd_tls_security_level` parameter in your `main.cf` above. Perhaps (1) the string was lost when you doing copy-paste or (2) you have it in `master.cf` file. That's why I ask you to post the output of `postconf -n` and `postconf -M`

Comment: The second error was delt with, but since i dont have access to the MX records the resolution of the first one is pending. At least now when you set the mailing server manualy without contacting the mx records the mail gets delivered, so that should be the remaining problem. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you've cross-posted this question in [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192632/problem-with-setting-up-mailing-server) as well. I suggest you to remove it as [cross-posting activity is discouraged in Stack Exchange universe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/260672), especially in [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yep that was posted first.. removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your [parameter](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_tls_auth) `smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes` doesn't allow you to skip TLS communication. Therefore, if a SMTP client isn't able (or refuses) to do TLS, your MTA will refuse the connection.
As an example, your telnet session is cleartext (no TLS).

<s>You might be missing `smtp_use_tls=yes` in your `/etc/posfix/main.cf`</s>

Comment: Parameter `stmp_use_tls` only used to **send** email. OP problem was about **receiving** email.

Comment: You're right, I missed this information.